# CSS animations - How to toggle direction with one keyframes declaration

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I would like a div to animate to the right when a button is clicked, then animate again to the left when the same button is clicked. I would like to use only one `keyframes` declaration. Is this possible by swapping classes?

I've tried this in CodePen, but unfortunately, the div snaps back after the first animation, then refuses to animate the second time.

I'm not using CSS transitions because I want to be able to use features of CSS animations like a bouncing effect.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var movedOver = false;

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var buttonEl = document.querySelector(".one");

    if (movedOver) {
      buttonEl.classList.remove("do-the-slide");
      buttonEl.classList.add("do-the-slide-back");

    } else {
      buttonEl.classList.remove("do-the-slide-back");
      buttonEl.classList.add("do-the-slide");
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 800px;
  >div {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
  }
  >div.do-the-slide {
    animation: moveOver 1s ease-out;
  }
  >div.do-the-slide-back {
    animation: moveOver 1s reverse ease-out;
  }
  >.one {
    background: red;
  }
}

button {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

@keyframes moveOver {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
</div>

<button>Clicky</button>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vaadao

Comment: is that the animation you are using? because if it is, transitions would be a lot easier.

Comment: I agree, transitions would be easier. But I eventually want to add various aspects to the animations like a bounce effect that I can't do with just transitions.

Comment: You might find this article useful https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: Thanks Jacob Gray for the reference link. That was key in solving this puzzle:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, so after fiddling with this for a while, I've come up with what I consider an acceptable solution for using one keyframes declaration to drive both directions of animations. The key to this was forcing the browser essentially reset through a redraw, as explained here: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/ (thank you Jacob Gray for posting that reference).

Once I got that working with the reset, I used javascript (yes, this requires javascript) to add the reverse direction when animating back (this could be in a separate class and just add that className).

And, it works. I'm now able to animate in both directions using one keyframes declaration. Pretty snazzy, and drastically minimizes the css code.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var movedOver = false;
  var direction = "";

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var el = document.querySelector(".one");

    el.classList.remove("do-the-slide");
    el.offsetWidth = el.offsetWidth;

    if (direction === "toRight") {
      direction = "toLeft";
      el.style.animationDirection = "reverse";

    } else {
      direction = "toRight";
      el.style.animationDirection = "";
    }

    el.classList.add("do-the-slide");

  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 800px;
  >div {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
  }
  >div.do-the-slide {
    animation: moveOver 1s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  >.one {
    background: red;
  }
}

button {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

@keyframes moveOver {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(120px, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
</div>

<button>Clicky</button>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/risingtiger/pen/zqqMpv

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for `forwards`, but even then, a transition will be needed to make it simple.

```css
p span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 1s;
}
p:hover span {
  animation: 1s moveOver forwards;
}
@keyframes moveOver {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
```

```html
<p><span>span</span>
</p>
```

I f you want to use a single animation, you will eventually have to deal with paused and steps and i m not even sure that will be easy to handle or possible. I see no fun here :)

for a bounce effect, final value at 50% should be good enough:

```css
p span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 1s;
}
p:hover span {
  animation: 2s moveOver infinite;
}
@keyframes moveOver {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
```

```html
<p><span>span</span>
</p>
```

Comment: The forwards of the animation was indeed key. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score -2):

I made a pen based on this post and the css-tricks article here [codepen](https://codepen.io/PingVoid/pen/bQBmxE)

**HTML**

```
<h2>Single keyframe-track burger collection</h2>
<p>(each span uses only one track to play for- and backwards)</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cell">
    <h3>Default</h3>
    <div>
      <button class="burger">
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
      </button> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cell">
    <h3>Merge</h3>
    <div>
      <button class="burger burger--merge">
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
      </button> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cell">
    <h3>Rotate</h3>
    <div>
      <button class="burger burger--rotate">
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
      </button> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cell">
    <h3>Spin</h3>
    <div>
      <button class="burger burger--spin">
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
        <span class="burger__bar"></span>
      </button> 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(#5E802B, #2F4016);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  h2,
  h3,
  p {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
}

.cell {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  div {
    margin-top: auto;
  }
}
/****************
* Burger Styles *
*****************/
.burger {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;

  &__bar {
    height: 10%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-duration: .4s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      top: 25%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      bottom: 25%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    }
  }

  &.close .burger__bar {
    animation-direction: reverse;
  }
  &.open .burger__bar {
    animation-direction: normal;
  }
  // default
  &.animate .burger__bar { 
    animation-play-state: running;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation-name: default-top;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation-name: default-middle;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation-name: default-bottom;
    }
  }

  &--merge.animate .burger__bar {
    animation-duration: .6s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation-name: merge-top;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation-name: merge-middle;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation-name: merge-bottom;
    }
  }

  &--rotate.animate .burger__bar {
    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation-name: rotate-top;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation-name: rotate-middle;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation-name: rotate-bottom;
    }
  }

  &--spin.animate .burger__bar {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation-name: spin-top;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation-name: spin-middle;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation-name: spin-bottom;
    }
  }
}

/*__________________
       DEFAULT
____________________*/
@keyframes default-top {
  50%  {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes default-middle {
  50%, 100% {visibility:hidden;}
}
@keyframes default-bottom {
  0%   {}
  25%  {}
  50%  {
    bottom:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    bottom:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
/*__________________
       MERGE
____________________*/
@keyframes merge-top {
  20%  {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0) scale(1, 1);
    //width: 100%;
  }
  50%  {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0) scale(0.2, 1);
    //width: 20%;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.2, 1);
    //width: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(1, 1);
    //width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes merge-middle {
  50%  {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0, 1);
  }
  51%{visibility:hidden;}
  99% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0, 1);
  }
  100% {visibility:hidden;}
}
@keyframes merge-bottom {
  20%  {
    bottom:40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  50%  {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg) scale(0.2, 1);
  }
  100% {
    bottom:40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
}
/*__________________
       ROTATE
____________________*/
@keyframes rotate-top {
  50%  {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-middle {
  50%  {transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);}
}
@keyframes rotate-bottom {
  50%  {
    bottom:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    bottom:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

/*__________________
       SPIN
____________________*/
@keyframes spin-top {
  50%  {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(315deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin-middle {
   50%  {visibility:hidden;}
  100% {visibility:hidden;}
}
@keyframes spin-bottom {
  50%  {
    bottom:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(450deg);
  }
  100% {
    bottom:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(405deg);
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
burgers = document.querySelectorAll('.burger');
for (let i = 0; i < burgers.length; i++) {
     burgers[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       this.classList.remove("animate");

       var bars = this.querySelectorAll('.burger__bar');
       for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
         // Reset span animations - https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
         void bars[i].offsetWidth;
       }

       if (this.classList.contains("open")){
         this.classList.remove("open");
         this.classList.add("close");
       } else {
         this.classList.remove("close");
         this.classList.add("open");
       }  
       this.classList.add("animate");
    });
};
```

Comment: Here we also like some explanation why your proposed solution works better then the original source code provided in the original post. Please follow this guide to improve your answer [answer]